# Threshold implementation of ciphers

Tags: block-cipher, side-channel-attack, threshold-cryptography

What is the principle behind threshold implementation of block ciphers and how is this protecting against side channel attacks?

Comment: Nice question  Can you give a reference which discusses this topic?

Comment: look at: "Threshold Implementations Against Side-Channel Attacks and Glitches" , @ https://www.esat.kuleuven.be/cosic/publications/article-847.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the principle behind threshold implementation of block ciphers

The idea is that we take every secret state of the cipher (be it the key itself or an internal state value) and convert that into a "threshold" representation, where the logical value of the secret state $s$ is actually implemented by $t$ different physical values $s_0, s_1, \dots, s_{t-1}$, in such as way that knowledge of $t-1$ of the physical values gives no information about the logical value $s$.

The most common way to implement this is with xor-sharing; if $t=2$, then each logical state $s$ is represented by $s = s_0 \oplus s_1$; if $s_0, s_1$ can both 1 with probability $0.5$, then learning just one of them gives no information about $s$.

The obvious question is "how do you do operations with these threshold representations?".  Linear/affine operations are easy: to negate, you just flip one of the physical components.  To xor, you xor the two values component-wise: $(s_0, s_1) \oplus (t_0, t_1) = (s_0 \oplus t_0, s_1 \oplus t_1$)

Nonlinear operations are a tad trickier; to perform an AND operation, what we can do is pick a fresh random value $r$, and compute $(s_0, s_1) \land (t_0, t_1) = (s_0 \land t_0 \oplus (s_1 \land t_1 \oplus r), s_0 \land t_1 \oplus (s_1 \land t_0 \oplus r))$. This works because we have DeMorgan's theorem: $(s_0 \oplus s_1) \land (t_0 \oplus t_1) = (s_0 \land t_0) \oplus (s_0 \land t_1) \land (s_1 \land t_0) \oplus (s_1 \land t_1)$ (which generalizes to arbitrary threshold values.  And, we stir in fresh randomness $r$ because otherwise the physical values would no longer be equidistributed.

With NOT, XOR and AND operations, any block cipher can be constructed.

> how is this protecting against side channel attacks?

The idea is that even if the attacker can get some information about the state of $t-1$ secret values simultaneously from a side-channel attack, that doesn't tell him anything about what's going on with the cipher itself.

---

I was asked to put in a reference; the earliest general reference I know is [Toward Sound Approaches to Counteract Power-Analysis Attacks](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007%2F3-540-48405-1_26.pdf)  by Chari et al; in particular, see section 3.3 "Encoding"

Comment: Thanks! I must admit I sow some answers, but non of them was that clear crystal

Comment: So, please correct me if I'm wrong, in order to implement, say, AES S-BOX with threshold logic, I can add the mask in the input, and then create a new S-BOX, say T-BOX, such that T(x+s) = S(x), and generate new s and new T each time I need to calculate S(x). Is that right?

Comment: @EvgeniVaknin: that'd be expensive - creating a fresh SBox each time would be costly.  One way I've seen is to implement a threshold implementation of $x^{254}$ (the nonlinear part of the sbox) based on the threshold multiplication identity $(s_0 + s_1)\times(t_0 + t_1) = (s_0 \times t_0) + (s_0 \times t_1) + (s_1 \times t_0) + (s_1 \times t_1)$ (where $+, \times$ are $GF(256)$ operations); still rather costly, but better than rebuilding the sbox each time...

Comment: @EvgeniVaknin: actually, as squaring in $GF(256)$ is linear, you can implement $x^{254}$ with 7 squarings (cheap) and 4 threshold multiplies...

Comment: Can you give a reference to put this question and your nice answer into context? I asked the OP as well.